# Deploying meteor app to intranet

Tags: node.js, apache, meteor, redhat

I am needing some help with deploying this meteor app I made onto our works INTRANET server. I bundled the app to make it a node app and installed node,npm,and mongodb onto the intranet server. When I go through setting up the environment variables with

```
export PORT=3000
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/databasename
export ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000
npm install
node bundle/main.js
```

I get a blank web page. In Apache I set up a virtual host in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf such as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName servername.dcn
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /timesheet http://localhost:3000/
< /VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas as to why I'm getting just a plain blank page instead of the app? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: `PORT`, `ROOT_URL`, and `MONGO_URL` should be capitalized. Does that fix it?

Comment: I'm sorry I will fix the question. I do have it capitalized when I am starting the app. So no that doesn't fix it

Comment: you get a blank web page when you go to which URL? (the server and port directly, or via the proxy)

Comment: When I go to servername.dcn/timesheet I get a blank page. When I go to localhost:3000 I get the app fine.

Comment: Do you have a HTTP error code when you visit servername.dcn/timesheet? If so you may want to check your apache logs for errors. You can check by looking up the network tab in the chrome console and refreshing the page

Comment: When I look at the error_logs it shows  
  
    [error] File does not exist: /var/www/html/blahblah.css, referer: http://servername.dcn/timesheet  
    [error] File does not exist: /var/www/html/blahblah.js, referer: http://servername.dcn/timesheet

Comment: which operating system are you using?